# Jquery nested click function abort child if container is triggered

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have onclick method in table  tag.I also have it in my  tag.
I'm just trying to cancel the click method on  when the delete button in  is pressed.

```
  @foreach (var item in Model.PickupTemplate.PickupBags.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id))
                            {
                                <tr id="pickupBagRow-@item.Id" onclick="RedirectToBagDetailsPage(@item.Id)" style="cursor:pointer;" class="bagList">
                                    <td>@item.BagName - @item.BagOrderId</td>
                                    <td>@item.TotalBillOfLadingWeightPhysical</td>
                                    <td>@item.TotalBillOfLadingWeight</td>
                                    <td>@item.TotalBillOfLadingCount</td>
                                    <td><a onclick="DeletePickupBag(@item.Id)"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i></a></td>
                                </tr>
                            }
```

How can i do it using jquery or javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the inner click event on the `a` element from propagating up the DOM to the `tr` for it to be caught there too.

To do this, and also to improve the quality of your code, use unobtrusive event handlers which are assigned in JS code, not in your HTML. From there you can access the event as an argument to the event handler and call `stopPropagation()` on it.

As you've tagged the question with jQuery, here's how to do it:

```js
$('.bagList').on('click', e => {
  let itemId = $(e.currentTarget).data('item-id');
  
  // redirect logic here...
  console.log('Redirect', itemId);  
});

$('.bagList a').on('click', e => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  let itemId = $(e.target).closest('.bagList').data('item-id');
  
  // delete logic here...
  console.log('Delete', itemId);
});
```

```css
.bagList { 
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  @foreach (var item in Model.PickupTemplate.PickupBags.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)) 
  {
    <tr id="pickupBagRow-@item.Id" data-item-id="@item.Id" class="bagList">
      <td>@item.BagName - @item.BagOrderId</td>
      <td>@item.TotalBillOfLadingWeightPhysical</td>
      <td>@item.TotalBillOfLadingWeight</td>
      <td>@item.TotalBillOfLadingCount</td>
      <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i>Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Here's the same logic in plain JS:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.bagList').forEach(bagList => {
  bagList.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let itemId = e.currentTarget.dataset['item-id'];

    // redirect logic here...
    console.log('Redirect', itemId);
  })
});

document.querySelectorAll('.bagList a').foreach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    let itemId = $(e.target).closest('.bagList').data('item-id');

    // delete logic here...
    console.log('Delete', itemId);
  });
});
```

Comment: It works but when I click the delete button it works twice

Comment: For example, when I choose the one with id of 2, the one with id of 3 is also followed.

Comment: I would suggest there's an issue in your HTML or JS which is different to the example I gave above. I'd suggest starting a new question about it - although be sure to include the actual HTML out, not the CSHTML